# SharePoint 2013 server vs Online MasterPage Css

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Is there any difference in the css and masterpage for online vs server edition?

Can i use a online site trial edition and make css changes, and then use that css on SharePoint server

Answer (score 2):

It is not adviced. I know that the css classes in Online in many cases has an `o365-`prefix for example. So there is at least little changes between the two.

Since updates are rolled out at a higher pace Online, there is also a risk of mismatch in actual DOM structure etc.